# Obtener valores de un string en c#

Tags: c#, parsear, querystring

Estoy intentando obtener los valores de un `string` que contiene una url con un `QueryString`.

Este es un ejemplo de la URL:

```
string url = "http://example.com?id=gdjh48vnnnvwsid1dkif84ndn?id2=cjodfnuvbvmf47747";
```

Cómo veis se trata de un `string` y no un `QueryString` ya que no se trata de la dirección de la página dónde estoy sinó de una url que obtengo con un `HTTPRequest`.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de parsear y obtener los valores de la url (en este caso `id1` y `id2`) sin utilizar `Split`, `Replace`, etc... ya que esto no es garantía de que funcione el 100% de las veces (en el valor de `id1`, por ejemplo, aparece `id1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método ParseQueryString de la clase HttpUtility.

Recuerda que deberás añadir una referencia al ensamblado System.Web si no lo tienes ya en tu proyecto.

```
        string url = @"http://example.com?id=gdjh48vnnnvwsid1dkif84ndn&id2=cjodfnuvbvmf47747";
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

        foreach (var key in queryString.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {queryString[(string)key]}");
        }
```